# Combining values from multiple columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hierarchy structure consisting of A,B,C,D. Each entity has a one-to-many relationship to its child (A -> 1:N -> B -> 1:N -> C -> 1:N -> D). 
I have another entity, lets call it X, which can be linked to one of those hierarchical entities using `LevelID` and `LevelTypeID` fields (`LevelID` is a foreign key to A,B,C or D and `LevelTypeID` is a foreign key to a look up table which contains the names of A,B,C and D)

Based on supplied `LevelID` and `LevelTypeID`, I need a query which can give me the current hierarchical entity and any higher parent level entities.

The following is some sample data in the 4 tables

```
   A
         ID       
         --
         1       
   B
         ID       A_ID
         ----     -----     
         10       1
   C
         ID       B_ID
         ----     -----
         100      10
   D
         ID       C_ID
         -----    -----
         1000     100
         1001     100
```

Using  **LevelId = 100, LevelTypeId = 3** (C), query should return:

```
   LevelTypeId    LevelId
   -----------    -------
   3               100
   2               10
   1               1
```

Using **LevelId = 1000, LevelTypeId = 4** (D), query should return:

```
   LevelTypeId    LevelId
   -----------    -------
   4               1000
   3               100
   2               10
   1               1
```

I was using query below, but I am not getting the correct results, especially when I filter on **LevelId = 100, LevelTypeId = 3**

```
select LevelTypeId, LevelId
from
   (    select  
            a.ID as [1], 
            b.ID as [2],
            c.ID as [3], 
            d.ID as [4]
        from A a
        left join B b on a.ID = b.A_ID
        left join C c on b.ID = c.B_ID
        left join D d on c.ID = d.C_ID
        where 
            (@levelTypeId = 4 and D.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 3 and C.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 2 and B.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 1 and A.ID = @levelId)

   ) p   
unpivot
   (LevelId FOR LevelTypeId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS unpvt
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: I'm really confused by your schema here. All you give us is ID, Parent, and your letter classes. How are these related to levelid and leveltypeyid? It might help if instead of using the literal names in your schema, you use more descriptive functional names here.

Comment: Its in the second paragraph: "LevelID is a foreign key to A,B,C or D and LevelTypeID is a foreign key to a look up table which contains the names of A,B,C and D"

Comment: Why don't you walk me through your first example, because it's really unclear to me why that's the expected result of the proposed query. This is your data and it makes sense to you, but it's not being explained super clearly from my perspective. For example, where does `LevelId=101` fit into this at all? It doesn't appear in either column of the table we're given.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: @BlueChameleon . . . Are the LevelIds as nicely structured as in the question?  That is, is level <n+1> simply level <n> + some digit?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: that 101 was a typo. Sorry

Comment: @BlueChameleon . . . Off hand, I would say the problem is that the joins should be `left outer join`s rather than `inner join`s.  Does that fix the problem?

Comment: It look's like you're trying to build a recursive query. It might help to know what SQL engine you're using to know what other tools we might have access to.

Comment: @Gorgon Linoff - sorry again. I was using left joins, just removed the "left" to try something and then pasted the query into the question

Comment: @DavidMarx - SQL Server.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2739732/819544

Comment: Im having a hard time understanding how I can use that example. In it, he has one self-referencing table. In my example I have 4 tables that reference other tables instead of themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing query is returning all levels in the join, because the only level selection is occurring in the `where` clause - if *any* level matches the criteria, then *all* levels are selected. Instead, try:

```
select LevelTypeId, LevelId
from
   (    select  
            a.ID as [1], 
            b.ID as [2],
            c.ID as [3], 
            d.ID as [4]
        from A a
        left join B b on a.ID = b.A_ID and @levelTypeId >= 2
        left join C c on b.ID = c.B_ID and @levelTypeId >= 3
        left join D d on c.ID = d.C_ID and @levelTypeId >= 4
        where 
            (@levelTypeId = 4 and D.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 3 and C.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 2 and B.ID = @levelId)
            or
            (@levelTypeId = 1 and A.ID = @levelId)

   ) p   
unpivot
   (LevelId FOR LevelTypeId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS unpvt
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b678/5).